# Magento 2.2.5: Email Template Order Admin

Tags: magento2, email-templates, order-email

I'm looking for explanation about email template in admin.

As you can see, this button will send an email to my gmail account.

[image]
And as far as i know, magento use `order_new.html` to render html to email, but even when i changed it, the html is still the same, am i missing something here?

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\email\order_new.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!--@subject {{trans "Your %store_name order confirmation" store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var formattedBillingAddress|raw":"Billing Address",
"var order.getEmailCustomerNote()":"Email Order Note",
"var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
"layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order area=\"frontend\"":"Order Items Grid",
"var payment_html|raw":"Payment Details",
"var formattedShippingAddress|raw":"Shipping Address",
"var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description",
"var shipping_msg":"Shipping message"
} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order.getCustomerName()}}</p>
            <p>
                {{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}
                {{trans "Once your package ships we will send you a tracking number."}}
                {{trans 'You can check the status of your order by <a href="%account_url">logging into your account</a>.' account_url=$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1]) |raw}}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>' store_email=$store_email |raw}}{{depend store_phone}} {{trans 'or call us at <a href="tel:%store_phone">%store_phone</a>' store_phone=$store_phone |raw}}{{/depend}}.
                {{depend store_hours}}
                    {{trans 'Our hours are <span class="no-link">%store_hours</span>.' store_hours=$store_hours |raw}}
                {{/depend}}
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
            <h1>{{trans 'Your Order <span class="no-link">#%increment_id</span>' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}</h1>
            <p>{{trans 'Placed on <span class="no-link">%created_at</span>' created_at=$order.getCreatedAtFormatted(2) |raw}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            {{depend order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
            <table class="message-info">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()|escape|nl2br}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/depend}}
            <table class="order-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Billing Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Payment Method"}}</h3>
                        {{var payment_html|raw}}
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Method"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}</p>
                        {{if shipping_msg}}
                        <p>{{var shipping_msg}}</p>
                        {{/if}}
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Customize email templates using the Magento Admin :**

1. In the Magento Admin, navigate to **MARKETING** > Communications > **Email Templates**
2. Click **Add New Template**.
3. If you want to use a default template as a starting point, in the **Load default template** section, choose the template and click **Load Template**. The path to the configuration settings for each default template displays in the **Currently Used For** field in the Template Information section.
   Make note of this path because you will need it later when you configure this new template to be used instead of the default template.
4. In **Template Name**, enter a name to identify the template in the Magento Admin.
5. In **Template Subject**, add plain text to use as the Subject of the emails sent using the template you create. This field can contain system variables.
6. Customize template content. For details, see the section on customizing content.
7. In **Template Styles**, optionally add   CSS
    styles for the template. These styles are added inside of a <style> tag in the <head> of the email. Typically, you’ll use the LESS files to make style changes to emails because some email clients don’t support styles in <style> tags.
8. Click **Save Template**.
9. Now that you have created a template, you must configure that template to be used:

   1. If you haven’t done so already, log in to the Magento Admin as an administrator.
   2. Click **STORES** > Settings > **Configuration** > SALES > **Sales Emails**.
   3. In the left pane, locate the section that contains the template you want to override. This is the section referenced by **Currently Used For** in your new template. (See step 3 earlier in this section.)
       
      For example, if you created a “New Order” template, the configuration section is **Order** as the following figure shows.
   4. Select your newly created template from the list.
   5. Click **Save Config**.

Comment: Oh, thanks for reply :)
But i wanna custom email template programmatically, but as far as i know, i've to override this `order_new.html`. But what've i change is not working.

Comment: i give you example :-                                                                                                         In this case the path to default email template will be – ..\vendor\magento\{module}\view\frontend\email\email_template.html.

For example: ..\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\email\order_new.html.  --->  php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: i've change content in that file and run deploy already, but it doesn't change ..

Comment: have you override template in your theme folder ?

Comment: No, i want to test in this `order_new.html` first. Just to make sure this is the correct template that i need to override.

Comment: wht are you not getting. there are two ways to override your template(1) add in current theme folder (2) load in transction email template in amdin

Comment: So you are saying is what i change in magento core `order_new.html` is doesn't work at all? I know how to override template, but all i do right now is testing by changing `order_new.html` content.